# Как включить автокомплит html в js файле VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Я решил попробовать `React` и там нужно писать `HTML` разметку в методе `render` но в нем не работает автокомплит `HTML` так как считается что файл `js` и значит писать только на `js`.Как мне включить автокомплит `HTML`? создавал с помощью `create-react-app`